# World Map Framework for jQuery or HTML5

Tags: html, jquery, ajax, dictionary

I have a project which requires an animated world map on its home page similar to [this example](http://www.ammap.com/examples/flight_routes). Flash is not an option which leaves me with html5 css jquery or other ajax framework.

Do you know any World Map Framework for jQuery, HTML 5 or other ajax frameworks?

The data does not need to be dynamic all I want is for the lines representing the **from** and **to** destinations, to be animated.

Comment: The issue with this is that it may potentially require a canvas element, in which case you'd lose support for most IE users.

Comment: And to think that the solution should work with IE.

Comment: Haha. Well, it's definitely possible. I know Google maps works in IE, and I think that application does what you're trying to do, plus more functionality.

Answer (score 4):

In my personal order of preference: OpenLayers, Leaflet or Polymaps

http://openlayers.org/

http://leaflet.cloudmade.com/

http://polymaps.org/

All open source, all Javascript, all IE compatible (at least for IE>8, I think)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following mapping software product which is based on HTML5 / Google Map instead of Flash:

[iMapBuilder HTML5 Map Software](http://www.imapbuilder.com/html5-mapping/)
Map templates based (alike amMap), but use HTML5 maps instead of Flash Maps. Let you create interactive maps easily with pushpins, lines, mouse-over effects, etc.

[Flight Routing Map Base a Custom Google Map](http://www.imapbuilder.net/interactive-map-samples/category-legend-map-filter.php)
This is a flight routing map which is based on Google map, created using gmap editor.

Answer (score 0):

AmMap switched from flash to JavaScript quite a long time ago, and the demo above is now made with JavaScript.